# How do nested transactions work with triggers and different isolation levels in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions

I need to answer two questions. Here's an overview:

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A(x INT)
CREATE TABLE B(x INT)
CREATE TABLE C(x INT)
```

and 2 triggers:

```
ALTER TRIGGER ATr ON A
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE

    INSERT INTO B 
        SELECT * 
        FROM inserted;
    COMMIT
END

ALTER TRIGGER BTr ON B
FOR INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO C 
        SELECT * FROM inserted;
END
```

and the INSERT triggering the ATr trigger `INSERT INTO A VALUES(3)` is done on REPEATABLE READ isolation level, and the default isolation level for this database is READ COMMITTED.

And I need to answer two questions:

- On which isolation level will the ATr trigger execute?
- On which isolation level will the BTr trigger execute (if at all)?

I have problem understanding how these nested transactions are going to work. Will any transaction inside a LEVEL SERIALIZABLE transaction ever execute? Are they even nested in this case? What happens if a lower isolation level is inside a higher isolation level or the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is documented here [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

And you can examine this behavior by running

```
select CASE transaction_isolation_level
WHEN 0 THEN 'Unspecified'
WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncomitted'
WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Repeatable'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Serializable'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Snapshot' END AS transaction_isolation_level
from sys.dm_exec_requests
where session_id = @@spid
```

wherever you are curious about the currently-active isolation level.